# ActiveAdmin Carrierwave Image not appearing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

Got a strange issue. When uploading images via ActiveAdmin in development mode, images get displayed in the `show page`. However, when it comes to uploading them in production mode, there are no image previews.

I have checked the entries in the table and they're there. Additionally, there's a `404 image error` popping up in the console too.

Does this have anything to do with permissions on the directories? The `public` directory is set at `775`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you see errors from the production server?

Comment: @maxpleaner, the production.log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add this to `config/environments/production.rb`

`config.serve_static_files = true`